# How to reload the main file in Python console?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm doing updates to other modules imported in my main file, and I can reload them on the fly in the console and get the new behaviour immediately via

```
import importlib
importlib.reload(module_name)
```

How can I do this for the main file?

I tried `__name__` but did not work.

PS: I have gigantic datasets and I hate running again the main file after tiny changes, takes forever.

Comment: Check out this similiar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/437591/3420371

Comment: @CurtLH I don't see how this answers my question. I think I'm already doing the same thing as in the link you put.

Comment: Why don't you move the functions you need to reload to another module and reload that one?

Comment: @FranciscoCouzo great idea, although hacky.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your code in the main file into a `main` function and add this to the end:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This will let you reload the module while also letting you run it normally. However, after you reload, you have to call `module.main()`.

Comment: I have my code in this format already. But how do I reload the main file?

Comment: `import module` first, then call `importlib.reload(module)` whenever you make changes.

Comment: ``NameError: name 'module' is not defined``

Comment: replace module with whatever your main module is called

Comment: ``NameError: name 'boundary_prediction_normal_estimation' is not defined``

Comment: did you import before calling reload?

Comment: The main file doesn't need to be imported, it is the main file. This would cause infinite recursion.

Comment: No, you can only reload a module if you import it. Otherwise just rerun it.

Comment: That was the whole point of my question. Thanks anyway. Some people suggested a hack: putting the main file code in a file and importing it from a different file.